# a static struct array to keep track of all structs

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, struct, static-variables

I have to create a struct, a static variable to keep track of how many structs are alive and also a list of all current structs. I'm having trouble creating this list and the appropriate constructor. So far I have

```
class MyStruct{
public:
    static int i;
    static MyStruct *AllStructs;
    MyStruct(){i++; (AllStructs++)=this;} //error happens here
};

int MyStruct::i=0;
MyStruct MyStruct::*AllStructs;

int main(){...}
```

As you can see I tried to do it by creating a static array that gets added to as part of the constructor, but the compiler gives me an error: "lvalue required as left operand of assignment" in the place I indicated. It's not letting me assign new structs to my static array.

What am I doing wrong? Keep in mind pointers are the bane of my life so please explain it to me as you would to a small child. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `AllStructs` is just an uninitialised pointer, not an array - use a `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Do you allocate `MyStruct MyStruct::*AllStructs;` anywhere ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define `MyStruct MyStruct::*AllStructs;`, all you are doing is allocating memory for one single pointer to a `MyStruct` object, not actually creating space for an array of them. This array you want needs to have a valid memory location initialised for it to live in, where it can store its copy of all the pointers you want it to. That's likely to get messy though, so you should use a static `std::vector` instead to manage the memory allocation for the `MyStruct`. Simple as this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
class MyStruct{
public:
static std::vector<MyStruct*> AllStructs;
MyStruct(){AllStructs.push_back(this);}
};
std::vector<MyStruct*> MyStruct::AllStructs;


int main() {
    MyStruct ms;
    MyStruct ms2;
    std::cout << MyStruct::AllStructs.size() << std::endl;

}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: That works great, thanks for your help. Now, I'm trying to make an iterator to access individual members of AllStructs, but <br/> vector<MyStruct*>::iterator vi=*AllStructs.begin();   tells me "AllStructs was not declared in this scope" (give me a minute to figure out how to format this)

Comment: For the life of me I can't figure out how to add a linebreak in these comments. Just ignore the <br/>, I hope you can figure out what I'm trying to say.

Comment: It's MyStruct::AllStructs, not AllStructs, that you need to name